# Appveyor: Running command after deploy on each affected environment

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, appveyor

My company has recently switched from automatic migrations on our Entity Framework databases to now relying on a command being run to migrate and afterwards seed the database.
We want this to run on the database of each environment that is being deployed to via Appveyor, so when pushing to a specified branch Appveyor builds, deploys and then runs the migrate and seed command on each environment after the deploy is completed.

We usually place all build and deploy configuration in a yaml file, but there doesn't seem to be any way to run commands after deploy on the environment itself. The yaml script command `after_deploy` runs command as part of the build process, not the environment.

The Appveyor environment has a setting `After deployment command` that seems to be the key, but it requires the "runCommand" provider to be allowed on the server side. The reason for this is understandable, but how do I go about setting this up?

The guides I've found haven't really given anything. Nothing applicable on SO, and the link to Microsoft that Appveyor prints as an error in the deploy process is no longer accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because environment deployments run on shared worker severs, custom scripting is not allowed. But you could try a [deployment project](https://www.appveyor.com/blog/2015/11/04/deployment-projects/) approach. This divides your project into a "main project" and "deploymnet project" thus simulating a deployment environment, allowing you to decouple builds and deployments.

Assuming you are deploying to azure, you could then use [this script](https://gist.github.com/IlyaFinkelshteyn/fcbe7e1a3fe0f601944f1cf87c449be5) my colleague wrote to run your commands on the server.

If you are not deploying to azure, you could switch to [AppVeyor deployment agent](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/agent/) which uses web deploy behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks, the deployment agent seems to be the way to go.